# How to pipe program output so as to eliminate specific text

Tags: macos, pipe

I have a program which produces results to the terminal which contains a header and a footer. The header ends when the first line containing only '-' characters is encountered and the footer begins when the last line containing a '-'is encountered. I would like to pass the output of this program through another program that will cut out the header and footer, leaving only the data. I am not sure what the most efficient way to do this is. The files are roughly 20MB in size. I am running Mac OSX

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'awk' to do the work. Below is a awk program file I wrote in a file named clip.awk.
You can trim a data file that you described data.txt like this:
`$ cat data.txt | awk -f clip.awk`

Here is the program clip.awk:

```
BEGIN { state = 0; # HEADER
}
# match a line of all ----
/^-+$/ {
    if (state == 0)
        state = 1; # DATA
    else
        state = 2; # FOOTER
    # Skip to next line
    next;
    }
# print any line while in DATA section
    { if (state == 1) print }
```

Comment: shouldn't it be if (state==0 || state == 1)  in your first if statement? Otherwise after the first pass through a line no longer in the header it will automatically switch to state 2, the footer?

Comment: The block with the 'if (state == 0)' is only executed when you are a line of '---'. So any line past the header (until you hit the footer '---' line) does not execute that first block, and instead goes to the block with the print in it. Give it a try with a test file.